# How to connect to (localdb) database on server for Asp.Net membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to output a list of users `membership.GetAllUsers()`, but I get an exception:

> When establishing a connection to SQL Server error has occurred that
>   is associated with the network or with a specific instance. Server not
>   found or unavailable. Verify that the instance name is correct and
>   that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error upon detection of the
>   specified server or instance)

My connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SDC-20150804171038;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SDC-20150804171038.mdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have done  the test  connection in Server Explorer successfully. I think that the problem is neither in connection string nor in Server.

Do I need to override the membership in order to use the method getallusers()?

Comment: Is .NET 4.5.2 installed on the server? Is LocalDB installed on the server? Can you run `sqllocaldb info` and see the `v11.0` instance?

Comment: Did you set DataDirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect via sql server, you connection string should look like:

```
connectionString="data source=[Server Name];initial catalog=[Database Name];persist security info=true;user id=[SQL User];password=[SQL User Password]"
```

Find you database in SQL Server management studio, try to connect from there and then use the connection string from above.

Comment: Not applicable for LocalDB. Only integrated security.